# Mongoose, how to handle document category/type fields?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongoose, models

Let's say I have an **item** model that has the following fields: `_id`, `title`, `category`, `sub_category`. What would be a more efficient or better way to handle the `category` and `sub_category` fields?

The most obvious one would be just to make them as `String` types and add an `enum` validation. The other way would to make two separate collections of **Categories** and child collection **SubCategories** and then reference the **sub category** in the **item** which will also lead to the actual **category**.

From my understanding, when querying, it is more efficient to search by `ObjectId` rather than by `String` types, as well as that, it is better for indexing. However, this method also requires the use of `.populate()` which would slow down the querying.

So in the end, what would be more efficient? Or is one approach is better even if it less efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to implement it in a Graph DB,

Every element is category

now relationship is required between two categories

category1 <--- [sub-category-of] --- category2

https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-days-silicon-valley-implementing-graph-databases-with-mongodb

Comment: This way you can easily navigate all the categories,